# Python: creating string array with integers

Tags: python, arrays, list

I would like to create a large string array, that would look like this:

```
['x1_1', 'x1_1', 'x1_2', 'x1_2',................, 'x1_100', 'x1_100']
```

Is there an easy way for this? I want to have every value in the list twice. Not simply:

```
['x1_1', 'x1_2', ...,'x1_100']
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive. Are you simply looking to do something like `"x1_{}".format(num)"` and create a list of that n times? More importantly, show your own code for this attempt and explain what is not currently working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer version, which is hopefully more efficient:

```
a = [ 'x1_{}'.format(x) for x in range(1,101)]
a = zip(a,a)
a = [i for j in a for i in j]
```

a will contain your required list

Older version (not so efficient, but still works):

```
a = [ ['x1_{}'.format(x), 'x1_{}'.format(x)] for x in range(1,101)]
b = []
for i in a:
  b.extend(i)
```

b will contain your required list

Comment: @idjaw This is exactly what I asked for.

Comment: @Lanza It does, apologies. I had to double check because this way of doing it is really not advisable.

Comment: @idjaw Can you provide a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @idjaw can you please provide a more efficient version. I know that using two lists like this is not too efficient.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480380/python-creating-string-array-with-integers/36480629#comment60571896_36480414) answer

Answer (score 1):

```
['x1_{}'.format(x) for x in range(1,101)]
```

This is called *list comprehension*. It's the equivalent to the following:

```
array = []
for x in range(1, 101):
    String = "x1_{}".format(x)
    array.append(String)
```

**Edit:** yes, if you want to generate *exactly* 100 strings, then you'd need `range(1,101)` instead of `range(1,100)` because `range(a, b)` generates a list of numbers from `a` up to `b-1`.

**Edit #2:** if you want these strings to be repeated twice, try this:

```
array = []
for x in range(1, 101):
    Strings = ("x1_{} ".format(x)*2).strip().split()
    array.extend(Strings)
```

Comment: The upper limit is wrong. Please add a short comment why it should be `range(1, 101)`.

Comment: @Kay, done. Thanks for noticing my mistake

Comment: `*2/strip/split` seems like a *very* roundabout way to do what you could do with `array.append(String)` twice instead.  And instead of calling `array.append(String)` twice manually, we could use a loop -- and the loop could become part of the listcomp, resulting in `['x1_{}'.format(x) for x in range(1, 101) for _ in range(2)]`, which seems to me to be the One Obvious Way here.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension and string concatenation:

```
long_list = [ "x1_" + str(x) for x in range(1, 101) for y in range(2)]
```

Comment: This doesn't give OP the output they asked for.

Comment: Original question has been edited. Prior to those edits, the output was the same.